# Splitting an php array into teams

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array with a random amount of elements (it's a online game * random amount of users each time). I want to split this array into two teams, 
how is this achievable?

Example of an Array i have where 4 & 3 are ID's of users.

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 )
```

I haven't found so much information on this, and the information i have found is pretty hard for me to understand, so i would deeply appreciate some sort of explanation on how i can do this.

If i have not provided enough information, just let me know!
Thank you for taking your time reading my question!

//UPDATE
There will be 2 teams. 
There is no max number of players in each team, but preferably around 15 players per team.

Comment: What is the logic behind splitting into teams?

Comment: If you could give a fuller example of the input and how this would look in the output, it would help.

Comment: The users will be assigned a team and complete tasks to win over the other team.

Comment: How many teams should the array be split into? Is it a set number of teams? Is there a max number of people per team?

Comment: I think that two teams would be perfect:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use array chunk http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$count = ceil(count($input_array)/2);  // since you require 2 teams, you need to divide by 2
shuffle($input_array);
$teams =array_chunk($input_array,$count);
```

this will create two teams.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and additionally add the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function over the array

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$teams = 2;
$result = array_chunk(shuffle($array), sizeof($array) / $teams)
```

Comment: You mean `sPlice`, so as the rest of array can be used too.

Comment: The reason for my downote: **this answer does not work**. https://3v4l.org/jInQW  always test your code.